# Elsa Workflow 2 - When first startup workflow

Tags: elsa-workflows

I need to understand the first time workflow is started/restarted afterpublish
how to ?
inside javascript execution i need to understand it to clear my cache before execute it, i need something persistent across executions

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Maybe your question is out of the scope of SO. Here, you have to submit code you have written, with which you encounter a technical issue.

Comment: Your question is vague, but I guess you are asking about starting the workflow execution which in that case I should say a workflow can be started by a trigger or by creating an instance programmatically.